# How do I count the frequency of an item in a given range?

Tags: java, frequency, linear-search, frequency-distribution, symbol-table

I've been given a lab where I'm supposed to create a program that reads a file with 1000 random integers between 10 to 59 inclusive and generate a frequency table like this:

[image]

The ranges are 10 to 19, 20 to 29, 30 to 39, 40 to 49, and 50 to 59.
Here is a sample from the RandomInt.txt:
50
11
55
12
20
13
53
34
19
39
58
58
24
59
28
10
52
18
55
59
28
29
54

I've been successful at reading all the integers in a file, but for some reason my result for the frequency part is just 1 for every category. How do I put each integer in a range and count them all together within that range?
So far, here is my updated code that counts the frequency of each integer:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File file = new File("RandomInt.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
        SequentialSearchST<String, Integer> st = new SequentialSearchST<String, Integer>();
        
        
        int dataSet = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String key = sc.next();
            dataSet++;
            
            if(st.contains(key))
            {
                st.put(key, st.get(key) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                st.put(key, 1);
            }
        }
        
        for (String s : st.keys())
        {
            System.out.println("Integer: " + s + " Frequency: " + st.get(s));
        }
        System.out.println("Data Set Size: " + dataSet);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Prints *always* 1 because: *never* `st.containsKey(key)`!

Comment: [Edit] your question and post sample data from file `RandomInt.txt`

Comment: The only keys you add to `st` are the descriptions of the ranges, so you are never going to find the numbers you read from the file, even when one appears more than once.

Comment: for this specific case I would use an array for the counters: if you divide the number by `10` you almost directly get the index for such an array (some caution needed since the first range starts with `10`)

Comment: I managed to count the frequency of each integer in the file. But, I can't seem to get the range part working

Answer (score 0):

As @user16320675 says, you should probably do something numeric with arrays. See the following as a fairly kludgy fix as the use of strings for something essentially numeric is not really appropriate. Instead of just `st.contains(key)` you could call `st.contains(keyInRange(key))` - the following:

```
public static String keyInRange(String key) {
    final String[] RANGES = {
        "",
        "10 to 19",
        "20 to 29",
        "30 to 39",
        "40 to 49",
        "50 to 59"
    };
    return RANGES[Integer.parseInt(key) / 10];
}
```

but beware, because you're currently `put`ting in all ranges irrespective of key for some reason.

Comment: but I meant something like `count[Integer.parseInt(key) / 10] += 1` without the use of a map or similar

Comment: Yes I know but the solution has to integrate with the existing container class(es) being used

Comment: I updated my main() that reads the frequency of each item in the file. How exactly do I implement the String keyInRange?